# Are there any public web services that will check for an MTLS cert and response with application/json

Tags: web-services, ssl, mutual-authentication

A different thread pointed out a couple of services that would require a client MTLS certificate, accept any cert, and then respond with information about the SSL handshake/certs.

[HTTPS test server that checks client certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095559/https-test-server-that-checks-client-certificates)

These endpoints both return HTML.  Does anyone know of anything similar that returns application/json?

Comment: I never found such a service so I ended up creating my own.  If there is much interest I can see about making it public.

Comment: please release it and post an answer :)

Comment: I am working on releasing it, but it may be another couple of weeks before I make much progress on it.

Answer (score 10):

The URLs below will return application/json content upon successfully mutual TLS client certificate authentication. If no authentication is peformed, then HTTP error 403 is returned in the HTTP headers and the response is empty:

- https://certauth.idrix.fr/json (TLS 1.2 only)
- https://certauth.cryptomix.com/json (TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3)

The json returned in case of success contains various technical information about the established connection.

Comment: Is there a documentation on how to perform the http call?